# pandas str.split() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

say that I have a dataFrame with different names, some with 2 word names, some with 1 word names:

```
 Team A
 1   Zeus Odin John Wick Jason Bourne Loki
 2
```

And I want to have a result of

```
Team A Hero 1    Team A Hero 2    Team A Hero 3   Team A Hero 4   Team A Hero 5
    Zeus             Odin           John Wick     Jason Bourne    Loki
```

How would I go about using pandas str.split() fucntion with regular expressions in doing so?

Comment: how would you distinguish which is one word name and which one is two word name?

Comment: I do have a list in which every "Hero" is listed. Would that help? i.e.    HeroList = [ "Zeus", "Odin", "John Wick", "Jason Bourne", "Loki"]

Comment: Then you can directly add the names in the data frame
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2, lst3)),
              columns=['lst1_title','lst2_title', 'lst3_title'])

Comment: My bad, I have to be clearer. The problem would be then because my list of Heroes is significantly larger than the data set, its the entire list of heroes with 115 different names, each match has only 10 heroes.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have 115 list of names and only know to you are 15. is that right?

Comment: Almost, as in I have a single list of 115 names but I am given a dataframe of which 5 of those random names are in one team, and I would love to use the split function to split those names into columns

Comment: See the problem here is that how to know which is a single word name and which is a 'two word name'. until we have some reference to find this thing out we cant do it... and if there is a reference then should not be a difficult thing to acheive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to temporary replace the heroe's names containing a space by the name without space and reverse after using the `str.split()` function you want to use

```
import re
# create dictionary to assign the name of the hero with space to the one without
dict_hero = { hero: hero.replace(' ','')  for hero in HeroList if ' ' in hero}
# create the inverse of the previous dictionary, several ways but I choose this one
dict_hero_rev = { hero.replace(' ',''):hero  for hero in HeroList if ' ' in hero}
# now create the pattern and the replacement function to use in str.replace
pat = re.compile('|'.join(dict_hero.keys())) #look for the hero's name in your dict_heor keys
repl = lambda x: dict_hero[x.group()] # replace by the corresponding name in the dict_hero
# work on the column Team A
(df['Team A'].str.replace(pat, repl) #change the one with space to without
             .str.split(' ', expand=True) # split on whitespace and expand to columns
             .replace(dict_hero_rev) # replace the hero's names missing a space by the name with space
              .rename(columns={nb: 'Team A Hero {}'.format(nb+1) for nb in range(5)}))
```

With a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team A':['Zeus Odin John Wick Jason Bourne Loki',
                             'Hulk Thor Green Lantern Batman Captain America']})

                                           Team A
0           Zeus Odin John Wick Jason Bourne Loki
1  Hulk Thor Green Lantern Batman Captain America
```

and a list of hero

```
HeroList = ['Green Lantern', 'Thor', 'Hulk', 'Odin', 'Batman', 
              'Jason Bourne', 'Loki', 'John Wick', 'Zeus', 'Captain America']
```

then the above method gives you:

```
  Team A Hero 1 Team A Hero 2  Team A Hero 3 Team A Hero 4    Team A Hero 5
0          Zeus          Odin      John Wick  Jason Bourne             Loki
1          Hulk          Thor  Green Lantern        Batman  Captain America
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. @Ben.T I'm a beginner who started learning to code.  Unfortunately, I think that  `pat = re.compile('|'.join(dict_hero.keys()))` did not recognize the hero names and hence the code resulted in no new columns being created. Is there a reason why this happens?

Comment: I did, unfortunately even after that, it won't work and the result would be as same as the previous dataframe rather than creating new columns

Comment: @HarveyKoh another thing is that I never assign the result somewhere, so `df` is the same at the end, the code is not chaging `df` like this. Maybe do `df_split = (df['Team A'].str.replace(pat, repl) ... ` and the rest of the code and `df_split` should contains the result expected? try to find the reason, not a lot of ideas sorry :)

Comment: Cheers mate!! That did the trick! If I see you somewhere, I might have to buy you a beer